# Trying to Group By with a where statement but getting an error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I have a join table, UserClub. In it are club_ids and user_ids.

My goal is to do something like:

```
UserClub.where(club_id: club_ids).group(:user_id)
#=> { 3 => [1,5,10], 11 => [1, 12, 41], ... }
```

Where the key is the user_id and the value is an array of the club_ids.

Though, ultimately this is just a step in getting to the ultimate goal of grouping the keys in that hash (the user_ids) into those that have the same values.

So, let's assume the query above generated `{ 3 => [1, 5], 11 => [12, 15, 19], 4 => [1, 5], 51 => [12, 13, 14] }`

The ultimate goal is to end up with this: `{ [1, 5] => [3, 4], [12, 15, 19] => [11], [12, 13, 14] => [51]}`.

Though, it would be great if someone provided a solution with an ActiveRecord query to generate the ultimate goal, the real matter at hand is that my query throws an error. I don't know if I'm using it wrong. If so, what is the appropriate way to construct that query?

Error:

```
PG::GroupingError: ERROR:  column "user_clubs.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
LINE 1: SELECT "user_clubs".* FROM "user_clubs"  WHERE "user_c...
```

Schema is your usual join table. An id, a club_id, and a user_id. All integers.

Comment: which code leads to that exception?

Comment: The query above that I showed.

Comment: show user_club scheme please

Comment: @David See my answer it may help you.

Comment: @David jon table is users_club, seems that it is just through table not a join =)

Comment: replace group clause to `.group(:user_id, :id)`, and retry

Comment: @МалъСкрылевъ That didn't group them. The query went through, but they weren't grouped. I got back an ActiveRecord::Relation of the clubs with the club_ids specified in the where clause.

Comment: `I got back an ActiveRecord::Relation` that is good, but id you really need specific grouping use pure ruby

Answer (score 0):

You can get the expected result by

```
UserClub.where(club_id: club_ids).group_by{|record| record[:user_id]}
```

To get only club_ids

```
UserClub.where(club_id: club_ids).group_by{|record| record[:user_id]}.each{|k, v| v.map!{|val| val.club_id}}
```

Comment: I see. this maps the user_id to the club objects. Is there a way to have it map simply to the club_ids?

Answer (score 0):

If you really need a specific grouping, use pure `ruby`, so I believe it should be grouped as follows:

```
Club.where(id: club_ids).group_by {|c| c.users.map(&:id) }
```